# Helloworld component in React not working?

Tags: reactjs

A simple React component is not working for me.

helloworld.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-DOM';

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
      if (document.getElementById('root') !== null){
      return <h1>Test1</h1>
    } else{
      return <h1>Test2</h1>
     }
    }
  }

ReactDOM.render(<App/ >, document.getElementById('root'));
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>First react app</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="root"></div>
<!--load helloworld component-->

<script src="helloworld.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you define "not working" in more detail?

Comment: This is not how to include component in react. `<script src="helloworld.js"></script>`

Comment: Are you using WebPack or you just have 2 static files and open index.html directly in the browser?

Comment: It will be helpful if you'll add the error from the console so we could identify what's causing it.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you are running into a case sensitivity issue.

In `helloworld.js` try editing your import to:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

Comment: Beat me to it sir

Comment: Am trying to install react react-dom on my Mac but coming up with

```
pm WARN webpack-4-quickstart@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN webpack-4-quickstart@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for inotify@1.4.6: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    linux
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   darwin
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64...
```

Answer (score -1):

Had to install home-brew, node.js & npm again. got it working. BTW the single quotes worked just as well as double